# What else can I try to fix a clogged drain?

Tags: plumbing, clog

Our sink was draining slowly, but now it's *nearly* stopped.  I've tried several things:

- About four months ago I ran some liquid drain cleaner down the sink and things improved for a while

  - The downstairs sink got some liquid drain cleaner too and responded pretty well to that
  - The upstairs toilet was slow to flush and liquid drain cleaner appears to have been a permanent fix
- A week ago we tried the liquid drain cleaner again but the results were pretty poor
- Yesterday I used a plunger, checked the P trap (it was clear) and ran a 25' snake down the kitchen drain - none of which had any effect.  I was surprised how much resistance the plunger met though..

I'm not necessarily trying to fully diagnose the problem in this post.  I would like to know if there are some DIY tricks that I've missed, but the dishes are stacking up and I'm feeling like it might just be time to call in some professional help.

The kitchen sink drains (at a rough guess) 18 feet through a 1 1/2" pipe into the 4" main line under the house.  I ran all 25" through the kitchen drain without hitting any resistance (though the kitchen drain does make some 90 degree turns).

The bathroom at the other end of the house (closer to the end of the main line) also drains slowly after running for ~20 seconds.  However we haven't noticed any trouble running the shower or anything.

We have been living in this house for about 2 years.  We live in a rural area and this house is not hooked up to municipal sewage; we have our own septic system which was pumped when the house was sold.

Comment: You may have a blockage outside the house in the line to the septic system. Is the exterior piping plastic or ceramic?

Comment: @bib I believe it is plastic.

Comment: Do you know where the main clean-out is?  It should be on the main line, just inside or just outside the building, depending on where you live.

Comment: Just call a Roto-Rooter fellow or a local plumber.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a problem with your vent system. One of the pipes that comes out of the roof probably has some blockage and the drain can't breathe.

Comment: This seemed like a good guess, but after snaking out two vents, nothing improved : /